# Rviz core dump on docker

Tags: docker, ros

I am using tensorflow/tensorflow docker and installed ros on it. Here is my image: https://hub.docker.com/r/mpkuse/kusevisionkit/

I run my docker image as

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia -it mpkuse/kusevisionkit:v0.4 bash
```

I can run roscore and also the gui for rqt_image shows up correctly. However I cannot run rviz. Here is my error:

```
root@2fe10a6154c8:/app# rviz
[ INFO] [1539052958.662758017]: rviz version 1.12.16
[ INFO] [1539052958.662820468]: compiled against Qt version 5.5.1
[ INFO] [1539052958.662838215]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can I run rviz from the docker?

Comment: I think you can't open a GUI app like RViz in a Docker container.

Comment: This [link](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI) maybe help you

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a GUI app like RViz in a Docker container with the common way.

> The simple way is exposing your xhost so that container can render to
>   the correct display by reading and writing through the X11 UNIX
>   socket.
>
> ```
> docker run -it \
>     --env="DISPLAY" \
>     --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
>     --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" \
>     osrf/ros:indigo-desktop-full \
>     rqt
> export containerId=$(docker ps -l -q)
> ```

---

[**UPDATE**]:

- More complete is there in this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI)
- Also, this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/300113/docker-how-to-use-rviz-and-gazebo-from-a-container/) is similar.
- On this [stack_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791401/how-can-i-access-my-docker-container-in-heroku) is claimed that you can have GUI app such as the Rviz app on the Docker container.

Comment: I can run rqt_graph from the docker. But rviz still crashes. Yes, I have installed ros on the container

Comment: yes I run your command. With it I can run rqt_graph. rqt_graph running on container and shows up on the host. roscore running on the container. However I get a seg fault when i run rviz